# Can arrays just be used as iterators in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constructor, iterator

I'm just looking through std::vector constructors and seeing some people use the constructor that takes 2 iterators and just use it with arrays like:

```
int arr[5] = [1,2,3,4,5]
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + arr.size()/arr[0])
```

Why does this work? So is an array just an iterator as well?
Also one more question here:

```
 int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    vector<int> v4(a, *(&a + 1));
```

What exactly is this doing and why is it different from the other thing above?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, square brackets for arrays? `arr.size()` is not a thing. Play a bit here before posting https://godbolt.org/

Comment: That first "working" example is fantasy code. It should be `std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + sizeof arr / sizeof *arr);` . Native arrays have no `size()` member.

Comment: *Why does this work?* -- A "regular" pointer is an iterator.  Given that fact, you should be able to work out why the (fixed) example works, given that arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> int arr[5] = [1,2,3,4,5]
> std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + arr.size()/arr[0])
> ```
>
> Why does this work?

This doesn't work.

> So is an array just an iterator as well?

An array is not an iterator. But an array can implicitly convert to a pointer to first element which is an iterator for the array.

---

> ```
> int a[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
> vector<int> v4(a, *(&a + 1));
> ```
>
> What exactly is this doing

This is an unnecessarily complex way of writing:

```
std::vector<int> v4(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

Comment: Why is the +1 necessary? Doesn't &a just return the address then you're adding +1 to that address and dereferencing it..? Still kinda confused why do you add 1 and why do you dereference it because wouldn't that just return the first element itself and not a pointer to it?

Comment: @tommyk `Why is the +1 necessary?` because without it you would have a pair of pointers to the first element which would be an empty range. `why do you dereference it` Because if you don't indirect through the pointer to array, then it wouldn't be a pointer to integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int arr[5];

int *begin=arr;
int *end=arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);

std::vector<int> v(begin, end);
```

Here `arr` (as in begin=arr) is a "pointer", which can be used like an iterator. So `begin=arr` is an "iterator" to the beginning of the array and `end` is an "iterator" to the "beginning + 5".

*To be a little more precise: Here the name of the array "decays" into a pointer. In many circumstances the name can be used as a pointer and would be similar to `&arr[0]`, i.e. a pointer to the first element.*

The construction `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` goes back to the old C days and returns the number of elements in an array. `sizeof` by itself only returns the size in bytes, but if you divide that by the size of a single element, you get the number of elements.

So now that you have a correct "begin" and "end" iterator, you can construct a `std::vector<int>` from it. It's just one of the constructors of vector, which takes two iterators.

---

Your other questions is completely different from the first one.

`vector<int> v4(a, *(&a + 1));`

Now I am not sure this makes entirely sense. Perhaps you have typo here. This would try to call a vector constructor taking an `int[]` or `int*` as the first parameter and an int as the second parameter.

The signature would be `std::vector<int>::vector(int*, int)`, but I do not see such a constructor in the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: You might mention that in most contexts the name of an array decays into a pointer to its first element. That's why `arr` in `int *begin = arr;` is a pointer. In `sizeof(arr)` the name doesn't decay, so it's not a pointer; it's the name of the array. +1.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Will change.

Comment: Side Note, C++17 added [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), a handy tool for getting the size of an array without `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`. This function works on all Standard library containers as well to assist in writing generic code. Note that it still does not work on a pointer resulting from array decay. If you don't have C++17, take a look at the possible implementation in the linked documentation page and you'll see it is almost ludicrously easy to write your own version.

Comment: `std::size`, `std::begin/end`, `std::data` and `range` are really good additions to the std library.

Answer (score 0):

The first piece has several errors:

```
int arr[5] = [1,2,3,4,5]
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + arr.size()/arr[0])
```

The correct version would be:

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
```

where `arr` plus "the number of elements in `arr`" is a pointer just past the end of `arr`.

In the second piece, `*(&a + 1)`, is a pointer. `&a` is a pointer to `a` which is an array of 5 integers. Thus adding 1 advances the pointer `sizeof(a)` bytes (5 times the size of an integer). Hence, again the result is a pointer just past the end of `a` and thus the vector is initialized with the elements of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a typo

```
int arr[5] = [1,2,3,4,5]
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + arr.size()/arr[0])
```

It seems you mean

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] ));
```

Though if your compiler supports the C++ 17 you could write

```
#include <iterator>

int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + std::size( arr ));
```

Arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

From the C++ 17 Standard (7.2 Array-to-pointer conversion)

> 1 An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown
> bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The
> temporary materialization conversion (7.4) is applied. The result is a
> pointer to the first element of the array.

Consider the following demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::cout << "sizeof( arr ) = " << sizeof( arr ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "sizeof( arr + 0 ) = " << sizeof( arr + 0 ) << '\n';
}
```

Its output might loop like

```
sizeof( arr ) = 20
sizeof( arr + 0 ) = 4
```

As it is seen from the output the array designator `arr` was converted to a pointer in the expression `arr + 0`.

The same way if an array is used as an argument expression and the corresponding parameter type is not a referenced type when the array is converted to a pointer to its first element.

There is no constructor in the class template `std::vector` that has the first parameter having a referenced type to an array.

But there is a template constructor that accepts two first arguments of the same type

```
template <class InputIterator>
vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

So in this declaration

```
std::vector<int> v(arr, arr + sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] ));
```

there is used two above constructor where two first arguments are converted to pointers of the type `int *`.

Pointers have the same operations as a random access iterator. Thus the vector is created using the range of integer values `[arr, arr + sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] )`

As for this expression

```
*(&a + 1)
```

then the expression &a has the type `int ( * )[5]` that points to the array a.. The expression `&a + 1` points to the address pass the last element of the array. The dereferenced  expression *(&a + 1) has the type int[5] that denotes an array that again used as an expression is converted to pointer of the type `int *`.

So you have in fact two expressions of the type `int *` in this declaration

```
vector<int> v4(a, *(&a + 1));
```

However this approach is not correct because you may not dereference a pointer that points after a valid object.

Comment: "*It seems you mean ... `arr + size( arr ) / sizeof( arr[0] )`*" - in that situation, `size(arr)` would need to be `sizeof(arr)`. `size(arr)` and `sizeof(arr)` are very different things.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. It was a typo.